# Typescript paths not resolved

Tags: typescript, webpack

I've been trying to get path resolving working in my project, but I can't find a way to make it work.
My project is an electron project that uses electron webpack.

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

I would like to register paths for @main and @render for ./src/main and ./src/renderer
My tsconfig.json looks like this at the moment:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "newLine": "lf",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "DOM"],
    "typeRoots" : ["./node_modules/@types"], 
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@main/*" : ["main/*"],
      "@render/*" : ["renderer/*"]
    },
   "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
   "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

Yet VS Code warns me, that it can't find the module. The line looks like this:

```
import { Api } from '@render/api'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: have you tried to restart the IDE and TS service? when you change the config TS has to be restarted to detect new changes.

Comment: Well, no I did not try turning it off and on again. It worked. Thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: Awesome! added it as an answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to restart the IDE and TS service. When you change the config TS has to be restarted to detect new changes.